# ArangoDB web interface connection refused

Tags: arangodb

I have arangodb installed on my server listening on port 20925 (assigned by my webhost)

I can connect successfully via the shell, and I can confirm that the process is running with that port as the endpoint.

I started the db like so:

```
sbin/arangod --daemon --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:20925 --pid-file ~/tmp/pid/arango
```

But if I try to connect via the web interface like so

```
http://www.EXAMPLE.com:20925/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html
```

I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I know that the port is open, but I'm not sure what else to look for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specify

```
--server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:20925
```

than the server will only bind to localhost. Use

```
--server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:20925
```

to bind to all available networks or

```
--server.endpoint tcp://A.B.C.D:20925
```

where A.B.C.D is the address of www.example.com.

Comment: Same error with either of the above, not sure what's gone wrong

Comment: Success! Not sure what the problem was, but eventually I got your A.B.C.D method to work.

Comment: If you run a custom arangod build in vagrant, make sure you bind to `0.0.0.0`, as `127.0.0.1` is really just the local host and won't be reachable from the host system (or use the actual network ip of the guest system).